# How to show unicode characters in matplotlib pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to show unicode characters in matplotlib, but it is not showing as unicode, rather it is showing as boxes. Here is the code and the result

[image: example]

How can I show unicode strings in matplotlib?

Answer (score 1):

use `matplotlib.rc('font', family='Your Font')` for displaying the required unicodes.